Wix: ComponentRef Filters
I have an easy setup but no idea how to make it happen.
I have a database feature that currently references a componentGroupRef of SSIS Package files.
My new situation requires different files to be copied to a folder depending on SQL Version.
The files are in their own ComponentGroupRef that is inside their own cmpFrag file.
So I'm trying to do this, but it's not allowed
<Component Id="ETL2016" Directory="ETL" Guid="{D05B8F9D-2815-4919-8ACC-AEED0F118BCC}" KeyPath="no" NeverOverwrite="no">
          <Condition><![CDATA[SQL_MASTER_VERSION = "13"]]></Condition>
          <ComponentGroupRef Id="Etl2016Component"/>
</Component>

<Component Id="ETL2022" Directory="ETL" Guid="{D05B8F9D-2815-4919-8ACC-AEED0F118BCC}" KeyPath="no" NeverOverwrite="no">
          <Condition><![CDATA[SQL_MASTER_VERSION = "16"]]></Condition>
          <ComponentGroupRef Id="Etl2022Component"/>
</Component>

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
